# AngularJS and using one modal for multiple functions

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, stored-procedures

I'm working on a site that uses WEB APIs (from a C# backend) and uses AngularJS in the front end. At one point, I have a ng-click that opens a Modal and warns the user that proceeding will **delete all test records** (dont' worry too much about this).

Upon clicking proceed a **sproc** is called (*from web-api controller->service->EDMX sproc*) etc. Anyway, I have another two other buttons that do the same thing (display a modal but with **slightly different wording**) and call the same sproc, but after the sproc fires it redirects to a different page.

Is it possible to use **one modal**, with different **template-urls** and re-direct to **different pages when the user clicks proceed/the modal closes depending on the button pressed**?

**P.S. Note modals not models**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a reuseable directive for this situation.

It allows you to pass in various template urls

```
<a template-link="/html/delete.html" confirm-dialog="deleteElement()">Delete</a>


'use strict';
/*global angular,console,$:false*/

angular.module('testmodule').

directive(confirmDialog', ['$modal', function($modal) {


    var modalInstance = null;

    var ModalCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            if (angular.isDefined(modalInstance) && modalInstance !== null) {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
        };

      };

      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
              confirmDialog:"&",
              tLink: '@templateLink'
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

              element.bind('click', function() {

                  modalInstance = $modal.open({
                      scope: scope,
                      templateUrl: tLink,
                      controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', ModalCtrl],
                      backdrop: 'static',
                      keyboard: false,

                  });

                  modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                      scope.confirmDialog();
                  }, function() {
                      //Modal dismissed
                  });
              });
          }
    };
}]);
```